# Remove nsobject from nsmutablearray after certain time

Tags: ios

I would like to add an "expiration date" to an nsobject when I add it to an NSMutableArray. After a certain time, I would like to remove that object from the array. What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: question lacks detail about the definition of "expiration date"

Comment: i basically want to remove the object from the array after 30 seconds

Comment: I would use `CACurrentMediaTime` to generate a time stamp for the object.  Then, in response to a repeating `NSTimer` with a 1 second time interval, scan the array and remove any object whose time stamp is more than 30 seconds old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom container class that uses an `NSMutableArray` (or `NSMutableSet` if you don't need ordering) internally.  Expose a method on your class like:

```
- (void)addObject:(id)object withExpirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate;
```

In that method you can add `object` to your internal array or set, and set up a timer to call a method to remove the object at the expiration date.  I imagine you can take advantage of `NSTimer`'s `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` initializer.